# can we add add_action('admin_init','myfunction') in wp-includes/functions.php

Tags: wordpress

I have a question regarding `add_action`, can i able to add `add_action` in `functions.php` that is `wp-includes/functions.php`

```
add_action('admin_init','myfunction');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but you should not since all your modifications will be overwritten when you upgrade wordpress. Use your theme's `functions.php` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i have 44 themes, should i need to put that code in all 44 themes functions.php

Comment: You either put it in your current activated themes' `function.php` if you want that function to be available only for that theme. Else you can create a plugin and put the code in it so that it is always available. Nothing complicated in creating a plugin btw.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put it in wp-includes for the reasons rrikesh states. You're just going to the code on update.

If you have a lot of themes within which you want common functionality, make them children of a parent theme.

The parent can hold all the common code in its own functions.php file and the children will be able to use it.

[Review the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) for information on Child Themes and how to implement them.